# Install4j 7.0.3 The Subtitle in the "Banner with Header" form does not appear

Tags: install4j

I am creating an installer using Install4j 7.0.3. I am trying to utilize the subtitle property of the form, 'Banner with header at the top', but the subtitle does not appear. [image: Showing subtitle value is set but not visible]

How do I make the subtitle appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitle is not used by this style in the default template. Go to Installer->Styles and edit the "Banner" style, you will see a single "Screen Title" form component whose "Title type" property is set to "Title".

If you want to display the subtitle in that style as well, add another "Screen Title" form component after the "Horizontal separator" and set its "Title type" property to "Subtitle".